# How to change default image rename?

Tags: images

When i upload image with same name Wordpress automatically adds the number before the extension like `some_name1.jpg`. Is it possible to change this process that id also added a bottom line like `soma_name_1.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only access `$file` and do something like below.

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_filter' );

function custom_upload_filter( $file ){
    $file['name'] = 'wordpress-is-awesome-' . $file['name'];
    return $file;
}
```

Also have a look how WP does it at  `wp-includes/file.php`